# Reinterviewing for a job after 15 months after not passing initial phone interview

Tags: interviewing, careers, reinterviewing

Beginning of last year, I was selected for the interview process for a position that I really liked. A recruiter (employee of the company) who use to work for the company contacted me for the position. My interview process ended after first phone interview and I was not provided any feedback as to why I didn't advanced to the next level.

Since then I have been preparing myself for similar positions and have been doing a lot of informational interview. I feel now I am better prepared for such interviews. Now, a very similar position opened again in the same company few weeks back and I want to reapply for the position.

Question: I am thinking to again contact the same recruiter (I verified that he/she is working for the same department/company) and expressing my interest again for the position. Is there anything else I should do (or NOT do) when I am contacting a recruiter for reconsidering me for the position? I don't want to say (or not say) something that would blow my chances away.

Comment: About contacting the same recruiter... if this is a recruiter with the company (direct employee), this may not be the best idea considering that they did not bring you in or provide feedback. Since you had a negative experience the first time around, you may want to start fresh.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of things can happen in a year. If I were you, without knowing the details of your previous interview process, I wouldn't reveal that you were previously considered for the position unless they bring up the subject first. You want to be judged based on what you have to offer them today, not what they didn't feel you had to offer last year. Otherwise, be honest, be engaged, and demonstrate your interest and enthusiasm for the position by coming up with meaningful and thoughtful questions to ask in the interview. If this is a place you want to work, invest the time to get to know it and don't be afraid to ask about the company culture, expectations, and advancement opportunities. Good luck to you, by the way...

Comment: I'd just add that be prepared to say what you've done in the last year that you think makes you a better fit if they do bring up "oh, so you interviewed here last year"

Answer (score 1):

Definitely contact the company and ask them if they would allow you to apply again.

A similar thing happened to me.  I applied for a position and got a phone call that I wasn't being picked for interview, and the HR person gave wishy washy reasons.  Three months later a similar job was advertised.  I rang the company and asked if they would accept me applying again, and the (different) HR person said they would, and gave me some tips as to tweak my CV and cover letter. I got an interview and the job !

Answer (score 0):

There are always a lot of unknowns in the interview process, and the thing you would hope is that it is the skills of the applicant that determines whether you get the job or not. I think interviewers don't always have the best idea of what the 'right fit' is necessarily, and to take anything they say personally just makes you feel worse when you face a similar situation next time.

There is definitely a big factor whether they know you have applied or not and whether it is the same person doing the recruiting or not. I think the fact that you reapplied for a similar job means that it is of interest to you, and I don't think it can work against you unless there was a specific reason they didn't want to hire you the first time and you need to avoid tripping the same alarm again. If you cannot obtain this information, then I would suggest that you look at this as being a new interview where you have gained more skills and experience as an employee, and that if this is the right timing for you then the rest will take care of itself.